# gcloud iam roles create: You can't create a role_id (...) which has been marked for deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

I'm creating a role in GCP under an organization, using gcloud command.
This role can be deleted/undeleted throughout its lifetime.

This used to work perfectly by undeleting the role if it already exists, but recently it fails.

When trying to undelete the role, I get an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.roles.undelete) NOT_FOUND: The role named organizations/12345678/roles/someRoleId was not found.
```

So it obviously doesn't exist. Also, when running

```
gcloud iam roles list --organization=12345678 --show-deleted
```

the role doesn't appear.

The problem is that when running the command

```
gcloud iam roles create someRoleId --organization=12345678 --file=config_file.yml
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.roles.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: You can't create a role_id (someRoleId) which has been marked for deletion.
```

There are roles that start with the same id, but none of them is similar, for example "someRoleIdJohn".

How can I find and delete this "ghost" role?

Comment: I am facing the same issue - cannot undelete role, cannot create a new one with same ID, deleted role does not show up anywhere. 

As far as I can tell from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#deleting-custom-role), this might happen if the role was deleted more than 7, but less than 44 days ago (within 7 days you can undelete it, after 44 days you can create a new role with the same role ID).

Comment: @Bogd Google support pretty much approved what you are saying. These roles are in a kind of "limbo" state and we couldn't find a way to resolve the issue. Until we may manage to come with a solution, we create another role with a different name until the original one is completely deleted.
I consider it a design flaw, but I don't think Google has any intention to fix it.

Comment: I have opened a ticket with them as well [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324585413?pli=1). Unfortunately, in my case, they seemed to be unable to reproduce (or understand?) the issue, and it was closed as "won't fix - intended behavior". Without a support contract, there is nothing more I can do, so I had to drop the issue :( I ended up independently using the same workaround of randomly generating the role name :)

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue, I have opened a ticket with the GCP issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324585413?pli=1). Unfortunately, they seemed unable to reproduce (or understand?) the issue, and all I got in the end was a "Won't fix - intended behavior", because "the issue is specific to your end" (even though I pointed to this question as an example of other people experiencing the exact same issue).

As far as I can tell, there are the following milestones for a deleted role (according to the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#deleting-custom-role)):

- Up to 7 days after deletion - the role can be undeleted
- 44 days or more after deletion - the role has been completely deleted, and it can be created from scratch once again

The problem is the in-between period - between 7 and 44 days after deletion. Undeleting the role fails (because the 7 days grace period has already passed), but creating a new role with the same ID is not possible (because the 44 days period has not yet passed, and the old role has not been completely deleted).

The only thing I could do was to work around the issue by creating a new ID for the role every time (basically randomly generate a role ID suffix).

Answer (score -1):

This is an expected behavior for deleted roles. You have ample time to undelete it in the event of accidental deletion. It takes 7 days for the role to be completely deleted. A workaround is to create a new role ID. Here is a document for reference in handling custom roles.[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#deleting-custom-role

Comment: I know this is the expected behavior, but as I mentioned in my question, undeleting this role returns an error that it wasn't found.